# Generate rig from mesh

Tags: rigging

Is it possible to generate a rig based on a mesh? I'm thinking something simple like having one bone per edge.
I'm going to look into scripting it I guess but if someone did something similar already it may save me the trouble.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It seems you have the same acquaintances :). Blender 2.49, that's a scary thought. But I'll look into it and the script, if I can lay my hands on it, would probably help.

Comment: EDIT: Armature from Edge Loop https://blenderartists.org/t/armature-from-edge-loops/515611/12 last update 2012, but liero was always very kind to help, you can try to ask. Previously posted unfolding (armature from faces) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/master/object_convert_to_armature.py (2.79) or extended https://blenderartists.org/t/unfold-transition/586992 (2.79 / 2.80) generates bones that expects rig these faces (not other mesh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add Skin Modifier to your Mesh (edge structure)
- Press "Create Armature"

[image]

Comment: It's noteworthy, that the mesh is *converted* to an armature. It has to duplicated, otherwise the original will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

If you have one connected edge loop, you can use [this script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69027/30849).

[image: result]

The mesh object has to be selected before executing the script.

```
import bpy

def CreateBoneChainFromVertices():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    if (None == obj):
        return

    if (obj.type != 'MESH'):
        return
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    edgesA = []
    edgesB = []
    for i in range(len(obj.data.edges)):
        ver = obj.data.edges[i].vertices
        edgesA.append(ver[0])
        edgesB.append(ver[1])

    chain = []
    chain.append(edgesA[0])
    while(True):
        current = chain[len(chain)-1]
        if current in edgesA:
            idx = edgesA.index(current)
            next = edgesB[idx]
            del edgesA[idx]
            del edgesB[idx]
            chain.append(next)
        elif current in edgesB:
            idx = edgesB.index(current)
            next = edgesA[idx]
            del edgesA[idx]
            del edgesB[idx] 
            chain.append(next)
        else:
            if (chain[0] in edgesA) or (chain[0] in edgesB):
                chain = list(reversed(chain))
            else:
                break

    amt = bpy.data.armatures.new(obj.name + "_vBones")
    rig = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + '_vRig', amt)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rig)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rig
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

    print(chain, "here we go")
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    for i in range(0, len(chain) - 1):
        bone = amt.edit_bones.new(str(i + 1))
        bone.head = obj.data.vertices[chain[i]].co
        bone.tail = obj.data.vertices[chain[i + 1]].co
    for i in range(0, len(amt.edit_bones) - 1):
        amt.edit_bones[i + 1].parent = amt.edit_bones[i]
        amt.edit_bones[i + 1].use_connect = True
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

CreateBoneChainFromVertices()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response and fix for 2.8. I just noticed the Skin modifier option, that also works for fork (like hand with fingers). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Leander, I'll study this

Comment: @Leander thanks a million for your example. It prompted me to actually write something to do the job automatically. There may be a gravity rig add-on before long.

Comment: @Kiskit Cool, please update me if there is an (open-source) github or blender.se post.

Comment: I'm not sure yet how I'm going to release it, but given how you took time to help me with code, I won't ask you for money if you want it ;). Also you're in the thanks on the youtube video's description. Look for "Gravity Rig Blender add-on introduction".

Comment: Thanks, looks cool, but I won't use it anytime soon.